# How to sort endpoint data on laravel 9?

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, axios

I have an endpoint (/comic/search), where the data structure looks like this:

```
{"item_type":"b","key_issue":null,"run":null,"bodytext":"<p>Avengers Vs the Xmen<\/p>","damaged":null,"title":"A+X","publisher":"Marvel","tags":"avengers","published":"2012-01-12","id":18,"issue":6,"stock":0,"price":1.99,"variant":"1","url":"\/books\/ax-6","cover":"http:\/\/fantasy-road.local\/assets\/img\/uploads\/20221219-172717.jpg","front":"http:\/\/fantasy-road.local\/assets\/img\/resized\/comic_flip\/20221219-172717.jpg","rear":"http:\/\/fantasy-road.local\/assets\/img\/resized\/comic_flip\/20221219-172706.jpg","summary":"Avengers Vs the Xmen","type":"Stories","relevance_score":2,"created_at":"19th\u00a0December\u00a02022"}
```

I have created a function in my ComicSearchController that looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Libraries\ComicSearch;

class ComicSearchController extends Controller
{

  const limit = 10;

  public function getComicData(Request $request)
{
  $query = $request->input('query');
  $sort = $request->input('sort');
  $more = ($request->has('more')) ? true : false;
  $debug = ($request->has('debug')) ? true : false;
  $results = ComicSearch::search($query, $more, static::limit, $debug);

  // Sort the comics data if the sort parameter exists
  if ($sort) {
    if ($sort === 'price') {
      usort($results, function ($a, $b) {
        echo "Comparing " . $a['price'] . " and " . $b['price'] . "\n";
        return ($a['price'] < $b['price']) ? -1 : (($a['price'] > $b['price']) ? 1 : 0);
      });
    } elseif ($sort === 'title') {
      usort($results, function ($a, $b) {
        echo "Comparing " . $a['title'] . " and " . $b['title'] . "\n";
        return strcasecmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
      });
    }
  }


  return response()->json($results);
}


}
```

and this is being called in the vue component, with this:

```
sortDirection(type) {
        if(type == 'alphabetUp') {
        this.loading = true
        this.alphabetisePlus = !this.alphabetisePlus;
        this.alphabetiseMinus = false;
        this.priceMinus = false;
        this.pricePlus = false;
        this.publishedMinus = false;
        this.publishedPlus = false;
        if(this.alphabetisePlus) {
          axios.get('comic/search?sort=title')
          .then(response => {
            console.log('Before sorting:', response.data);
            this.backstock = Array.from(response.data);
            this.backstock.sort((a, b) => {
              if(a.title < b.title) return -1;
              if(a.title > b.title) return 1;
              return 0;
            });
            console.log('After sorting:', this.backstock);
            this.loading = false;
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
      }
```

the data is being returned, but exactly as it was before it was 'sorted'. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you sorting it twice? Once in the PHP and once in the javascript?

Comment: @aynber I have absolutely no idea lol.